# How to clear error message in TextFormField in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In my code I validate phone number. If phone number is incorrect - I show error message. But, when user starts to edit number I want to hide this error message.

I've found the solution with `currentState.reset()`, but it seems not the good one. I have to handle issues with saving text and cursor position. And I still have one small artifact. Normally when I press and hold backspace - it deletes symbols one by one. If I do it when error message is shown - then error message disappears and only one symbol is deleted.

Does anybody know the right solution for this case?

```
final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
final RegExp _phoneRegex = RegExp(r"^\+{1}\d{10, 15}\$");
bool isError = false;
TextSelection currentPosition;

return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Form(
        key: _textKey,
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          validator: (str) {
            isError = true;
            if (str.isEmpty) {
              return err_empty_field;
            } else if (!_phoneRegex.hasMatch(str)) {
              return err_invalid_phone;
            }
            isError = false;
          },
        ),
        onChanged: () {
          if (controller.selection.start < 0 &&
              controller.text.length > 0) {
            TextSelection position =
                controller.text.length > currentPosition.start
                    ? currentPosition
                    : TextSelection.fromPosition(
                        TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
            controller.selection = position;
          }
          if (isError) {
            isError = false;
            currentPosition = controller.selection;
            if (currentPosition.start > controller.text.length) {
              currentPosition = TextSelection.fromPosition(
                  TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
            }
            String currentText = controller.text;
            _textKey.currentState.reset();
            controller.text = currentText;
            controller.selection = currentPosition;
          }
        },
      ),
    RaisedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        _textKey.currentState.validate();
      },
      child: Text(login),
    )
  ],
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found working and easier way

```
final _textKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

Widget _getPhoneInputForm() {
  final RegExp _phoneRegex = RegExp(r"^\+{1}\d{10,17}");
  bool isError = false;
  bool isButtonPressed = false;

  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 36.0),
        child: Form(
          key: _textKey,
          child: TextFormField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: hint_enter_phone,
                contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
                fillColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
                filled: true,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0)),
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blueGrey))),
            controller: _controller,
            validator: (str) {
              if (!isButtonPressed) {
                return null;
              }
              isError = true;
              if (str.isEmpty) {
                return err_empty_field;
              } else if (!_phoneRegex.hasMatch(str)) {
                return err_invalid_phone;
              }
              isError = false;
            },
            onFieldSubmitted: (str) {
              if (_textKey.currentState.validate()) _phoneLogin();
            },
          ),
          onChanged: () {
            isButtonPressed = false;
            if (isError) {
              _textKey.currentState.validate();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.teal,
        textColor: Colors.white,
        onPressed: () {
          isButtonPressed = true;
          if (_textKey.currentState.validate()) _phoneLogin();
        },
        child: Text(login),
      )
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: Here in Brazil this is called "G A M B I A R R A".

Comment: isButtonPRessed and errorText worked for me. I think using errorText inside InputDecoration is easier than using validator

Answer (score 41):

#### EDIT (Nov 2020)

`autovalidate` was deprecated after v1.19.0.
Instead use `autovalidateMode`:

```
Form(
  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction`.
  ...
)
```

---

#### Original post

here is a suitable solution to this problem.

You don't actually need to use `onChanged` or any tips causing side-effects, I solved it by creating a class property which is initialized to `false`:

```
bool _autovalidate = false;
```

The Form Widget has a named property `autovalidate`. You should pass it the previous boolean:

```
Form(
  key: _textKey,
  autovalidate: _autovalidate,
  ... 
)
```

And in your Submit button `onPressed()` method, you should update the `_autovalidate` boolean to be `true` if the form is `invalid`, this will make the form to auto validate the TextFormField on every `onChanged` call:

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_textKey.currentState.validate()) {
      print('valid');
    } else {
      print('invalid');
      setState(() => _autoValidate = true);
    }
  },
  child: Text(login),
)
```

I hope it helped Somebody.

Comment: This did the trick for me, careful management of auto-validation.  It resulted in vastly cleaner code.

Comment: I recommend using AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction only after the user has tried to submit the form once, using setState, otherwise, the user will start typing and the error will be shown immediately - not the best UX.

Answer (score 11):

### January 2021

```
...

AutovalidateMode _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.disabled;
```

```
Form(
  key: _textKey,
  autovalidateMode: _autovalidate,
  ... 
)
```

```
RaisedButton(
  onPressed: () {
    if (_textKey.currentState.validate()) {
      print('valid');
    } else {
      print('invalid');
      setState(() => _autoValidate = AutovalidateMode.always);
    }
  },
  child: Text("login"),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem here is `errorText` is **automatically managed** by the `validator` field of the `TextFormField`. At the same time, the simple solution is to handle the `errorText` **manually**.

**Step 1:** Create

- String field, `_errorText` initialised to `null`. The field will hold the error message that needs to be shown.
- Boolean field, `_error` initialised to `false`. The filed is `true` if there is an error otherwise `false`.

**Step 2:**

- Assign `_errorText` to `TextFormField`

**Step 3 (Important):**

- Make sure that `TextFormField` `validator` returns a `null` value.
- Handle the validation here and assign the proper error message to `_errorText`.
- Update `_error` state correspondingly.

**Step 4 (Important):**

- Reset `_errorText` and `_error`. This will remove the error from field soon as you start editing.

**Step 5:**

- Trigger field validation in the `onFieldSubmitted` and manage your code flow...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class WorkGround extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WorkGroundState createState() => _WorkGroundState();
}

class _WorkGroundState extends State<WorkGround> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _usernameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final _phoneNumberFocusNode = FocusNode();

  /*
  * Step 1.
  * */
  String _userNameErrorText;
  bool _userNameError = false;
  String _phoneNumberErrorText;
  bool _phoneNumberError = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: _usernameFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Username',
                /*
                * Step 2
                * */
                errorText: _userNameErrorText, // Handling error manually
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              /*
              * Step 3
              * */
              validator: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  if(value.isEmpty) {
                    _userNameError = true;
                    _userNameErrorText = 'Enter Username';
                  }
                });
                return null; // Return null to handle error manually.
              },
              /*
              * Step 4
              * */
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _userNameError = false;
                  _userNameErrorText = null; // Resets the error
                });
              },
              /*
              * Step 5
              * */
              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                _formKey.currentState.validate(); // Trigger validation
                if(!_userNameError) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_phoneNumberFocusNode);
                }
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              focusNode: _phoneNumberFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Phone Number',
                /*
                * Step 2
                * */
                errorText: _phoneNumberErrorText, // Handling error manually
              ),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              /*
              * Step 3
              * */
              validator: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  if(value.isEmpty) {
                    _phoneNumberError = true;
                    _phoneNumberErrorText = 'Enter Phone number';
                  } else if( value.length < 10) {
                    _phoneNumberError = true;
                    _phoneNumberErrorText = 'Invalid Phone number';
                  }
                });
                return null; // Return null to handle error manually.
              },
              /*
              * Step 4
              * */
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _phoneNumberError = false;
                  _phoneNumberErrorText = null; // Resets the error
                });
              },
              /*
              * Step 5
              * */
              onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                _formKey.currentState.validate(); // Trigger validation
                if(!_phoneNumberError) {
                  // submit form or whatever your code flow is...
                }
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I have achieved your both below functionality:

1) Hide error message when editing

2) validate input field when login button pressed

> Note: i have commented phone number regex and put validation for
>   string length < 10 digit for testing.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
//  final RegExp _phoneRegex = RegExp(r"^\+{1}\d{10, 15}\$");
  bool isError = false;
  bool isWriting = false;
  bool isLoginPressed = false;
  int counter = 0;
  String myErrorString = "";
  TextSelection currentPosition;
  final _textKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('MapSample'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: _textKey,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                validator: (str) {
                  myErrorString = "";
                  if(isLoginPressed){
                    isError = true;
                    if (str.isEmpty) {
                      myErrorString = 'err_empty_field';
                      return myErrorString;
                    }
                    else if (str.length < 10) {
                      myErrorString = 'err_invalid_phone';
                      validateMe();
                      return myErrorString;
                    }
                    /*else if (!_phoneRegex.hasMatch(str)) {
                      myErrorString = 'err_invalid_phone';
                      validateMe();
                      return myErrorString;
                    }*/
                    isError = false;
                    myErrorString = "";
                  }else{
                    myErrorString = "";
                  }
                },
              ),

              onChanged: () {
                counter++;
                if(counter == 9){
                  counter = 0;
                  isLoginPressed = false;
                }
                if(isLoginPressed){

                }else{
                  isWriting = true;
                  isLoginPressed = false;
                  myErrorString = "";
                  _textKey.currentState.validate();
                }
              },

            ),
            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                counter = 1;
                isWriting = false;
                isLoginPressed = true;
                _textKey.currentState.validate();
              },
              child: Text('login'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void validateMe() {
    if(isLoginPressed){
      currentPosition = TextSelection.fromPosition(
          TextPosition(offset: controller.text.length));
      String currentText = controller.text;
      _textKey.currentState.reset();
      controller.text = currentText;
      controller.selection = currentPosition;
      isWriting = false;
      isLoginPressed = true;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but there is couple of issues. First of all - there are some unnecessary fields and operations here (e.g. `isError` and `isWriting`). Also I prefer do not use "magic" numbers in code. In your case 9 is just empiric value which works only in concrete conditions. If you check your code with empty string - it doesn't work because `counter` not equals 9. Anyway, thanks for trying, it almost works, but this is not solution

Comment: Thanks for upvoting. I'll try to get better solution without extra variables and magic numbers.

Answer (score 3):

i have found that using a combination of `FocusNode` and `AtuoValidateMode.onUserInteraction` does the trick.

```
class _TextAutoValidateModeExampleState extends State<TextAutoValidateModeExample> {
  FocusNode node = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: TextFormField(
        focusNode: node,
        autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validator: (value) {
          if(node.hasFocus) return null;
          if (value!.isEmpty) return "value cannot be empty";
          if (!value.isEmail) return "not a valid email";
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// Call this method inside onChanged() and when its focusnode hasFocus
void formReset(GlobalKey<FormState> formKey, TextEditingController controller) {
  String stringValue = controller.text;
  TextPosition textPosition = controller.selection.base;

  formKey.currentState.reset();
  controller.text = stringValue;
  controller.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(textPosition);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an exemple , i think its not necessary to do onchange() , the function validate name do the work ...

```
 String validateName(String value) {
    String patttern = r'(^[a-zA-Z ]*$)';
    RegExp regExp = new RegExp(patttern);
    if (value.length == 0) {
      return "Name is Required";
    } else if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
      return "Name must be a-z and A-Z";
    }
    return null;
  }

  TextFormField(
                              controller: _lastname, validator: validateName ,
                              //initialValue: widget.contact.last_name,
                              decoration:
                                  InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last name'),
                            ),

void Save() {
 if (_keyForm.currentState.validate()) {
      // No any error in validation
      _keyForm.currentState.save(); 
................
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work at all. If I call validation from `onChanged` - it shows error always while phone is short yet. If I don't - the error message doesn't disappear.

Comment: delete onchange() from TextFormEditing...  use textFormEditi with just a controller and test .

Comment: Did you tried to do what you are recommending me? Without `onChanged` error message won't disappear at all. If you'll find the solution - check if it works properly and then publish here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, this works!

```
  TextFormField(

  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
  validator: (value) {
    if (_focusNode.hasFocus) {
      if (_validationError != null) {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          setState(() {
            _validationError = null;
          });
        });
      }
      return null;
    }
    String? old = _validationError;
    _validationError = widget.validator?.call(value);
    if (_validationError != old) {
      setState(() {});
    }
    return _validationError;
  },
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

final _formKey = GlobalKey();

AutovalidateMode _autovalidate = AutovalidateMode.disabled;

```
    Form(
          key: _formKey,
          autovalidateMode: _autovalidate,
          child: TextFormField(
                                    controller: _phoneNumberController,
                                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                    validator: validatorsController.miniLengthPhoneNumberValidator,
                                    onChanged: (value) {
                                      print("typing phone number");
                                      ValidatorsController.validateNumber(value);
                                    },
                                    inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                      // for below version 2 use this
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                                      // for version 2 and greater youcan also use this
                                      FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly
                                    ],
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        fontSize: 22,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal
                                    ),
                                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                      border: InputBorder.none,
                                      hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.grey,
                                          fontSize: 22,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontFamily: 'Inter',
                                          fontStyle: FontStyle.normal
                                      ),
                                      hintText: "(888)-000-0000",

                                    ),
                                    // onSubmitted: (String value) async {
                                    //   await showDialog<void>(
                                    //     context: context,
                                    //     builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                    //       return AlertDialog(
                                    //         title: const Text('Thanks!'),
                                    //         content: Text ('You typed "$value", which has length ${value.characters.length}.'),
                                    //         actions: <Widget>[
                                    //           TextButton(
                                    //             onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
                                    //             child: const Text('OK'),
                                    //           ),
                                    //         ],
                                    //       );
                                    //     },
                                    //   );
                                    // },
                                  ),
),

onPressed: () {
                  if(_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    sendOTP();
                  }else{
                    print('invalid');
                    setState(() => _autovalidate = AutovalidateMode.always);
                  }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    controller: vendorNameController,
                    validator: (value) {
                      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                        return 'Please enter Vendor Display Name';
                      }
                      return null; // Return null if the input is valid
                    },
                    textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Vendor Display Name',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                      ),
                      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                        borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey.shade300),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),'
```

Answer (score -2):

this format worked for me, Hope it helps someone....

```
validator: (value){
bool emailValid = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+").hasMatch(value);
                          
           isError = true;
           if(value.isEmpty){
                             return "Provide an email";
            }else if(!emailValid){
                return "Enter a valid email";
                              
                   }
                   isError = false;
                            return null;
                        },
```