# TextFormField displaying error message even after the values are inserted (using Form Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am experimenting with flutter and I am stucked with a silly problem. I have defined two TextInputField in a screen, and I am validating using Form. Everything is working fine, my only problem, error is not going away even after values which is inserted are fine.

Below is the screenshot before entering the value. Error is showing at the start of the screen as well.

[image: Screen at start]

Below is the screen after entering the value. When i click on signup button, error is still showing.

[image: Screen after entering the values]

You can see, value is getting printed in logs when i click on Sign Up button.

[image: Logs]

Widget Class

```
class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return SignUpState();
  }
}
```

State Class

```
class SignUpState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final _fbKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final UserDetails userDetails = UserDetails();
  bool _autoValidate = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScreenBg(
      AppString.additional_information,
      CustomCard(_getSignUpForm(context)),
    );
  }

  _getSignUpForm(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: Form(
        key: _fbKey,
        autovalidate: _autoValidate,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                RichText(
                  text: TextSpan(
                    text: AppString.welcome_to,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: AppColor.BLACK.toColor,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                    children: <TextSpan>[
                      TextSpan(
                        text: '${AppString.app_name}',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24,
                          color: AppColor.PRIMARY_COLOR.toColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 4),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                SubTitleText(AppString.lets_get_started),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: AppString.enter_name,
                    errorText: AppString.error_name,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.length < 4) {
                      return AppString.error_name;
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (name) {
                    userDetails.name = name;
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16),
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: AppString.enter_email,
                    errorText: AppString.error_email,
                  ),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value.length < 5 || !value.contains('@')) {
                      return AppString.error_email;
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (email) {
                    userDetails.email = email;
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 24),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: <Widget>[
                CustomButton(
                  AppString.sign_up,
                  () {
                    _onSubmit();
                  },
                  textColor: AppColor.WHITE.toColor,
                  bgColor: AppColor.PRIMARY_COLOR.toColor,
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _onSubmit() {
    if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _fbKey.currentState.save();
      print(userDetails.name);
      print(userDetails.email);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

This method is getting called when clicking on Sign Up Button.

```
_onSubmit() {
    if (_fbKey.currentState.validate()) {
      _fbKey.currentState.save();
      print(userDetails.name);
      print(userDetails.email);
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _autoValidate = true;
      });
    }
  }
```

Can someone help me in figuring it out, what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to set the `errorText` property, when validation fails it will show the message returned by the validator callback. So for fixing the issue, all you want is to remove `errorText` from your TextFormField.

Comment: I tried this as well, but unfortunately not working.

Comment: @SiddharthChandra I'm trying out your code in dart pad, will update the answer in a minute

Comment: Thanks @Midhun MP for your effort, I am really stucked with this problem.

Comment: @SiddharthChandra I've updated my answer, you have to remove the errorText property from your fields

Answer (score 4):

In my experience it is better to control the autoValidate property yourself. So following an example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60492188/1590073)

First set class Boolean variable :

```
bool _autovalidate = false;
```

Then pass it to your form:

```
Form(
key: _fbKey,
autovalidate: _autovalidate,
... 
)
```

Then in your validator:

```
validator: (value) {
                if (value.length < 5 || !value.contains('@')) {

                  return AppString.error_email;
                  setState(() => _autoValidate = true);
                }
                return null;
              }
```

Answer (score 4):

TextFormFiled has a new property since v1.19, called `autovalidateMode`. It provides multiple modes, but I think thast `AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction` works best. It only autovalidate the Form after each user interaction.