# How to remove validation warning in Text Form Field in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, user-interface, mobile

I have two Text Form Fields inside a Form in flutter. I have added validator to give warnings for invalid value. But I want the warnings to hide when the user starts typing again.

How to hide these warnings?[image: Validation in form fields]

I thought I could achieve this using onTap or onChanged function, but couldn't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: jsut add autovaliada on user interaction

Comment: is  autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always ?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810699/how-to-clear-error-message-in-textformfield-in-flutter

Answer (score 1):

`TextFormField`s have a `focusNode` property. While the user is editing a `TextFormField` the `FocusNode` associated with that field will have input focus. You can query the state of a `FocusNode` through the `hasFocus` property of the node.

So create and pass a `FocusNode` for each `TextFormField`, and then query the state of the relevant node in your validator function.

For example the code for the email `TextFormField` should look like this:

```
final emailNode = FocusNode();
...

TextFormField(
  focusNode: emailNode,
  validator: (value) {
    ...
    else if(widget.inputType == InputType.email &&
      !Validation.isValidEmail(value) &&
      !emailNode.hasFocus){
        return 'Please enter a valid email!;
      }
    },
  ),
```

This way when the user taps the email field and starts entering a new value the email field will have focus, so the last condition in the validator will be `false`, so the error message will disappear. When the user taps the password field the email field will lose focus, so the `!emailNode.hasFocus` will be true, and the error message under the email field will reappear, if the value in the email field is not a valid email address.

P.S. Next time post code instead of a screenshot please.

Answer (score 0):

try making autoValidationMode of your widgets onUserInteraction:

```
autovalidateMode:AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
```

Comment: I did this but it shows red lines and warnings till user types the correct email address. I want to show warnings only when user has completed typing and remove when user starts typing again. Is there any way to achieve this? I am new to flutter, so please help.