How to Remove validation text?
This is My Custom validation textfield
CmnTextField(
                    labelText: "Location",
                    controller: LocationController,
                    readOnly: true,
                    autoValidateMode: controller.unit
                        ? AutovalidateMode.always
                        : AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                    onTap: () async {
                      final result = await Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (_) => SelectLocation(whichLocation: 'From Location')));
                      if (result != null && result is Locations) {
                        _assignFromLocation(result);
                      }
                    },
                    validator: _validateInput,
                    enabled: isEdit
                        ? false
                        : controller.isMove ||
                            controller.isCustomMove ||
                            controller.unit,
                  ),

This is my validation Function:
String? _validateInput(String? value) {
    if (controller.unit) {
      if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
        return 'required';
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

When controller.unit this is condition is true make disable textfield and remove validation and when this condition is false at time i need on autovalidation mode so how i can achieve this?
if anyone have any idea then tell me

apply some code if your controller.unit is null validator: controller.unit  ? null  : _validateInput,

Then textfield autovalidation not working

Have you tried GlobalKey key with Form widget?

Try to wrap CmnTextField with Form widget.

yes it's already added still not working, you have any other solution?

Go to this link it might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55810699/how-to-clear-error-message-in-textformfield-in-flutter
